# How can I navigate to a particular fragment on app B after opening my app with intent from another app B

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an app A that directs user to another app B when the user clicks on update on app A.The app B contains a MainActivity which holds the fragment container and there are only 3 fragments. The first fragment is a splash screen, the second fragment contains a recycler view of all the apps, and when a user clicks any of the recycler view item, the name of the app on the recycler item is passed as a narvargs, and it takes the user to the third fragment, on the third fragment, which is the details fragment, it contains a button which user will click to download that particular app. the argument from the recycler view fragment is passed as a parameter to the function that makes the network call to download the app.

How can I navigate automatically to my third fragment screen which is the details screen of an app on App B when it is opened by intent when a user clicks update from app A to download the new update from my app B. This is the code I use to start my app B from app A

```
    private fun openAppStore(){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.component = ComponentName("com.package.name", "com.package.name.MainActivity")
        intent.putExtra("appName", "drivingApp")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

I passed an intent extra because I want to know the app name that opened the app B and used the name as parameter to make network call when a user clicks on the download button on the details screen

Answer (score 0):

You could use intents or the new standard (I think?) which is one main activity with multiple fragments using Navigation component. Paired with data binding this will free up a lot of code so you dont have to write a bunch of intents every where.

Check out the navigation codelab here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-create-and-add-fragment?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#4